# Cordova updating part of page

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I created a login page with javascript. After a succesful the function *loadMainActivity* is called. As of now the contents are as follows:

```
async function loadMainActivity(){
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "This is a text.";
}
```

It works. However, now I want to load a complete HTML page upon a succesful login. I tried several plugins to this end. However, all of them require me to load a file. As I see it I have two options:

1. Provide an extra file with the app. This would enable my users to see the source, which I don't want.
2. Host the file on a server. This would require my users to have an active internet connection when using the app, which I also don't want, for now at least.

I thought about "stringifying" the HTML page and replacing `"This is a text."` with the obtained HTML string. That way I could keep the source closed. But this seems like a lot of extra steps. Besides, I cannot find a good method to do this stringification of HTML text.

How to solve this problem for a Cordova app?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this can be done with the jQuery library, nothing specific to Cordova:

```
async function loadMainActivity(){
    $.get("mainactivity.html", function( my_var ) {
        document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = my_var;
    });
}
```